# Can't manipulate widget views from a service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I have a servive which starts when a button on a widget has been clicked (with pending intent), and in the service I am making some changes to the views of the widget and some writings in the database, the problem is everything else is working ine, except the view stuff, it's not changing anything, here's the code

```
private Intent serviceIntent;
    private RemoteViews remoteViews;
    private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    private int widgetId;
    private DataHelper dh;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        this.serviceIntent = intent;
        widgetId = serviceIntent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS)[0];
        dh = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvText, "Text 1");
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progressBar1, View.VISIBLE);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        // some writings in the database
    }
```

even though I am calling appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget it's still not updating anything, any ideas?

Comment: Is your `widgetId` correct?

Comment: yes, it's only 1 ID in the coming array

Comment: actually yes, jsut checked, and in the widget class, the one that extends AppWidgetProvider the ID there is another number